# How to run by gradle tests by <test> tag from testng xml

Tags: xml, gradle, testng

I'm using testng and gradle. My xml file name = "RegressionScope_PublicArea"
How can I run "LiveEducation" tests by gradle command.
E.g.

```html
"gradle test -DtestName=LiveEducation"
```

or

```html
"gradle test -PsuiteFile=RegressionScope_PublicArea -PtestName=LiveEducation"
```

MY RegressionScope_PublicArea.xml file:

`

```html
<suite name="Public Area" configfailurepolicy="continue" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
      <test name="LiveEducation">
        <packages>
            <package name="uiTests.researchEducation.learningCenter"/>
            <package name="uiTests.researchEducation.learningCenter.LiveEducation.publicArea"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
```

`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30872987/5944412

Comment: @BipinKumarChaurasia there is an exmaple of how to run xml file... I want to run only a <test name="LiveEducation"> from xml file